# Exception in thread main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an error and I am trying to figure out how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
private static void checkAnomalies(Name[] list){
    Name[] temp = new Name[list.length];
    int anomalyCount = 0;
    int popTwo = 0;
    int popOne = 0;
    String[] anomalies = new String[1065];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        temp[i] = list[i];
    }

    for (int decade = 0; decade < 11; decade++){

        for (int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++){
            int smallestIndex = getIndexOfSmallest(decade, index, temp);
            interchange(decade, index, smallestIndex, temp);
        }

        int rank = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i += 2){

            popOne = temp[i].getPop(decade);
            popTwo = temp[i+1].getPop(decade);

            if (popOne != 0){
                rank++;
            }

            if (popOne  == rank && popTwo != rank){
                String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One name (" + temp[i].getName() + ") for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i].getPop(decade) + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }
            else if (popOne != rank && popTwo == rank){
                String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "One name (" + temp[i+1].getName() + ") for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i+1].getPop(decade) + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }
            else if (popOne != rank && popTwo != rank){
                String decadeYear = decadeYears(decade);
                anomalies[anomalyCount] = "No names for " + decadeYear + ", rank " + temp[i].getPop(decade) + ".";
                anomalyCount++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

the error I am getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4429
at NameApp.checkAnomalies(NameApp.java:495)
at NameApp.writeAnomaliesToFile(NameApp.java:260)
at NameApp.main(NameApp.java:44)
```

I know that list.length is equal to 4429 and I know that the error is at this line here

```
popTwo = temp[i+1].getPop(decade);
```

how can I still use this but not go over 4429.

Comment: Change the condition for stopping the loop to two less: `for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 2; i += 2){`. You should be able to figure this out.

Comment: I couldn't run your code without all the relevant methods provided, but I think it's because you are doing `i += 2` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrease the limit on your loop to stop iterating before `i+1` exceeds the end of the array.

e.g. (note the `- 1`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i += 2){
```